# How to grab the other 'flagged' value if another entry/value for that particular also exists

Tags: sql, oracle

So I am running into an issue where my current system is flagging any value that was 'substituted out' and calculated during a separate data load process. Some sample data are as follows:

```
Value            Brand             Hour                  Code      Type
  5                G           10/16/2018 01:00 AM      'ABC'         A
 NULL              G           10/16/2018 01:00 AM      'MIS'         A
  12               G           10/16/2018 02:00 AM      'ABC'         A
  2                B           10/16/2018 01:00 AM      'ABC'         B
 NULL              B           10/16/2018 01:00 AM      'MIS'         B
```

What I want is whenever there are two (or more) entries, I want the view I create to grab the NULL value that has a data_code that is <> 'ABC' but still have a data_code = 'ABC' (as shown below)

```
Value            Brand             Hour                 Code       Type
 NULL              G           10/16/2018 01:00 AM      'ABC'         A
  12               G           10/16/2018 02:00 AM      'ABC'         A
 NULL              B           10/16/2018 01:00 AM      'ABC'         B
```

I've tried the following but not sure if this is correct: (is there a better way to do this?)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW 'VIEW_1' as
select CASE WHEN Data_code <> 'ABC'
            THEN select MIN(value_nb)
                   from Table_1
                   group by Brand, Hour, Type
            ELSE value
             END            VALUE
     , Brand
     , Hour
     , 'ABC'
     , Type
  from Table_1;
```

Comment: didn't getting your question. please brief it\

Comment: I want to grab the original (null) value but still have the view display the original 'ABC' data_code for it.

Comment: What is the unique key that this should be placed on? Brand + Type?

Comment: @JohnWick expected output

Comment: @Ravi the expected output in the 2nd block / table that you see (the one with 3 entries

Comment: @DanialWayne it's a composite key on brand, hour and type.

Comment: "whenever there are two (or more) entries" - what/how are you counting? There is only one entry for G/2am/A but that is in your output. There are two for each of the other 'key' combinations but they only have one row each in the output - so *only* the non-ABC and null entries, but with the code changed. I can see how to get that result, but I'm not sure I understand your logic, so I might be getting it for the wrong reasons...

Comment: @AlexPoole So any entry marked with 'MIS' is a value that is 'missing' or 'null'. I have a stored procedure written to substitute (based on certain logic) that null or missing value with a calculated value. However; in one of the views that I want to create, I want all of the ORIGINAL Values, have them labeled as 'ABC' (any value that is part of the 'original' data load).

Comment: What's the primary key of the `Table_1`? I see it's not `brand`, `hour` and `type`. Just to clarify, as asked by Alex Poole, how do we count? If two records have the same `brand`, `hour` and `type`, is it considered two entries?

Comment: And what is the 'original' value? Is this data representing the state after your procedure has run, and how do you know which values where already there and which it created? I'm sure this makes sense to you but we don't have the background or context to know how to interpret what you've shown.

Comment: @Junjie brand hour code and type. in the second its brand hour and type.

Comment: @AlexPoole the 'original value' is any NULL value. the stored procedure calculated a replacement (based off certain logic and rules) and flagged the original NULL value with 'MIS', etc.

Comment: and the counting?

Comment: It would have been helpful to explain all of that in the question from the start... I'm still not 100% sure I understand all of it.

Comment: @Junjie not sure what counting you are referring to.

Comment: @AlexPoole , my apologies I guess it made sense in my own head but wasn't sure which part was difficult to understand and which wasn't . thanks for your help (as always :))

Answer (score 0):

To summarise the comments, you need the 'ABC' rows where there is no matching 'MIS' row (based on the combination of brand/hour/type); plus the 'MIS' rows which also have a matching 'ABC', but with the code changed to 'ABC'...

You could union together two queries to get those subsets of rows:

```
select value
     , brand
     , hour
     , code
     , type
  from table_1 t1
  where code = 'ABC'
  and not exists (
    select *
      from table_1 t1_sub
     where t1_sub.brand = t1.brand
       and t1_sub.hour = t1.hour
       and t1_sub.type = t1.type
       and t1_sub.code = 'MIS'
  )
union all
select value
     , brand
     , hour
     , 'ABC'
     , type
  from table_1 t1
  where code = 'MIS'
  and exists (
    select *
      from table_1 t1_sub
     where t1_sub.brand = t1.brand
       and t1_sub.hour = t1.hour
       and t1_sub.type = t1.type
       and t1_sub.code = 'ABC'
  );

     VALUE BRAND HOUR                CODE TYPE
---------- ----- ------------------- ---- ----
        12 G     2018-10-16 02:00:00 ABC  A   
           G     2018-10-16 01:00:00 ABC  A   
           B     2018-10-16 01:00:00 ABC  B
```

or the second branch could presumably be simplified if there must always be a matching 'ABC' for each 'MIS':

```
select value
     , brand
     , hour
     , code
     , type
  from table_1 t1
  where code = 'ABC'
  and not exists (
    select *
      from table_1 t1_sub
     where t1_sub.brand = t1.brand
       and t1_sub.hour = t1.hour
       and t1_sub.type = t1.type
       and t1_sub.code = 'MIS'
  )
union all
select value
     , brand
     , hour
     , 'ABC'
     , type
  from table_1 t1
  where code = 'MIS';

     VALUE BRAND HOUR                CODE TYPE
---------- ----- ------------------- ---- ----
        12 G     2018-10-16 02:00:00 ABC  A   
           G     2018-10-16 01:00:00 ABC  A   
           B     2018-10-16 01:00:00 ABC  B
```

You could also do this with a single hit against the table, using analytic functions, in various ways; this is just one example which makes a null value take precedence over a non-null one:

```
select value
     , brand
     , hour
     , code
     , type
  from (
    select value
         , brand
         , hour
         , 'ABC' as code
         , type
         , row_number() over (partition by brand, hour, type order by value nulls first) as rn
      from table_1
  )
 where rn = 1;

     VALUE BRAND HOUR                CODE TYPE
---------- ----- ------------------- ---- ----
           B     2018-10-16 01:00:00 ABC  B   
           G     2018-10-16 01:00:00 ABC  A   
        12 G     2018-10-16 02:00:00 ABC  A
```